# Does Intuitionism extend to all type of science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

[Mathematical Intuionism argues that Mathematical object only exist as constructions of the Human mind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/), but would't this also mean all type of science are like so?

Since there is a requirement for an observer to make an observation. Since perception of external for an observer is a conjuration of the observers mind, wouldn't this mean that everything is intuitionistic?

Comment: If so, it will be Idealism.

Comment: Why isn't intuionism= idealism?

Comment: Did you actually find any counterexample from your sources that non-math/philosophy sciences contradicts with intuitionism?

Comment: The extended (beyond mathematics) version of intuitionism was introduced by Dummett and is called [anti-realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-realism):"In anti-realism, the truth of a statement rests on its demonstrability through internal logic mechanisms, such as the context principle or intuitionistic logic, in direct opposition to the realist notion that the truth of a statement rests on its correspondence to an external, independent reality."

Comment: I actually didn't but I don't get why one would think ointuitionism and idealism are not the same then

Comment: Anti-realistic idealism may still judge LEM (law of excluded middle) and law of double-negation as valid ideas expressed in everyday classic logic which constructive intuitionism normally judges not cautious enough and disallow...